# Terraform: Property file to env section

Tags: terraform

I have a .properties and I'd like to apply a template to generate env {} entries to my deployment.

Something like this:

```
          {{- range $key, $value := .Values.configurationOverrides }}
         env {
            name  = {{ printf "REST_%s" $key | replace "." "_" | upper | quote }}
            value =
```

Generate env {} entries:

```
  ...
  spec {
    container {
      image = "**"
      name  = "rest"

      env {
        name  = "REST_FROM_PROPERTIES_FILE"
        value = "VALUE FROM PROPERTIES FILE"
      }
      ...
```

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your .properties file ?

Comment: Sure:

id=rest
rest.servers=localhost:9092

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I assume you use Terraform 0.12.x

One part of the solution is [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks) which allow you to loop over a list of values and dynamically add env sections:

```
properties_list = [{ name: "MY_ENV_VAR", value: "VALUE", },]
dynamic "env" {
  for_each = var.properties_list
  name = env.value.name
  value = env.value.value
}
```

The hard part is parsing the properties file, as there is no out of the box way to do it in Terraform. You can use something like [jsondecode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsondecode.html) to decode JSON into a terraform object. So you could first transform your properties file into a JSON file (For example, using [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/properties-to-json)) and then decode that into a terraform object.

Answer (score 0):

Following the help of **Blokje5** I managed to make it with variables. It's not really loading from properties file, but it fitted my needs (which was not change Terraform code when need to change config/env vars) :

File terraform.tfvars:

```
kafka-rest-envs = {
  KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS                            = "localhost:9092"
  KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME                                    = "hostnamey"
  KAFKA_REST_ID                                           = "kafka-rest"
  KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS                                    = "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
  KAFKA_REST_CLIENT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG                      = "***"
  KAFKA_REST_CLIENT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL                     = "SASL_SSL"
  KAFKA_REST_CLIENT_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM = "https"
  KAFKA_REST_CONSUMER_RETRY_BACKOFF_MS                    = "500"
  KAFKA_REST_CONSUMER_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS                  = "25000"
  KAFKA_REST_PRODUCER_ACKS                                = "1"
  KAFKA_REST_CLIENT_SASL_MECHANISM                        = "PLAIN"
  KAFKA_REST_ADMIN_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS                     = "50000"
  KAFKA_REST_KEY_SERIALIZER                               = "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer"
  KAFKA_REST_VALUE_SERIALIZER                             = "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer"

}
```

And the Terraform:

```
...
      spec {
        container {
          image = "confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest"
          name  = "kafka-rest"

          dynamic "env" {
            for_each = var.kafka-rest-envs
            content {
              name  = env.key
              value = env.value
            }
          }
...
```

Thank you!